# How do I hide certain elements using this function?

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following function to scale each image when a user hovers over it.

```
$(function() {
    var imgScale = 4;
    $("img").each(function() {
        $.data(this, 'size', {
            width: $(this).width(),
            height: $(this).height()
        });
    }).hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            height: $.data(this, 'size').height * imgScale,
            width: $.data(this, 'size').width * imgScale
    });
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            height: $.data(this, 'size').height,
            width: $.data(this, 'size').width
        });
    });
});
```

The basic structure of the page is as follows:

```
<div id="product-container" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
    <div id="products" style="width: 50%; display: block; float: left;">
        <h2>Products</h2>

        <div class="product">
            <div class="image">
                <a href="page.php?product=123" title="Product 123">
                    <img width="80" height="60" src="product123.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="link">
                <p><a id="link-123" href="page.php?product=123" title="Product 123">Product 123</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="product">
            <div class="image">
                ...
            </div>

            <div class="link">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>

        ...

    </div> <!-- Close 'products' div -->
```

Using jQuery, I would like to hide all the `<p><a id="link-123"...> ... </a></p>` tags for the products that are not currently hovered over.

In addition to this, I would like to create a text overlay on the expanded image that gives the product name (e.g. "Product 123"). This could be extracted from the `title` attribute of the image itself.

This is very much a work-in-progress in its early stages, and as you have probably guessed I am new to jQuery. I'm just trying to get to grips with some of the basic features of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Fist you have to hide all links with

```
$('.link').hide();
```

In your hover function, you have to find the proper `<div class="link">` for your image. You can do this with by stepping up the tree to your `<div class="product">` and the down to `<div class="product">` (there are other possible ways to achieve that:

```
$("img").parents('.product').find('.link');
```

Now hide or show this elements.

Your complete code could look like.

```
$(function() {
    $(".link").hide();
    var imgScale = 4;
    $("img").each(function() {
        $.data(this, 'size', {
            width: $(this).width(),
            height: $(this).height()
        });
    }).hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            height: $.data(this, 'size').height * imgScale,
            width: $.data(this, 'size').width * imgScale
        }).parents('.product').find('.link').show();

    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            height: $.data(this, 'size').height,
            width: $.data(this, 'size').width
        }).parents('.product').find('.link').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the background info, but it's not quite what I was looking for. I would like all images and all links to be visible on page load, then as you hover over one of the images, the captions for all the _other_ images disappear. These should then reappear when the mouse is moved off the image. What happens with this new code is all links are hidden on page load, then they appear (and persist) as each image is hovered over. Sorry if I didn't explain the original question clearly enough!

Comment: I think I have it now - instead of finding ".link" in the immediate parent, I found ".link" in the "#products" div (the parent of the ".product" divs), and swapped the "show" and "hide" with each other.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood your question, but fine if my answer helped nonetheless.